# Excel #value error passing result of dynamic array formula to another function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, dynamic-arrays

I have the following data in columns A and B. I want to filter the table by group 1 to return only the group 2 values as an array and the perform an operation on that array (in this case `RANK`)

If I do that as 2 steps, it works just fine

`D2` formula is `=TRANSPOSE(INDEX(FILTER($A$2:$B$12,$A$2:$A$12=A2), ,2))` (I put the transpose just to make readable) and the `I2` Formula is `=RANK.EQ(B2, D2:G2)`

[image]

If I try to enter the function as `=RANK.EQ(B2,INDEX(FILTER($A$2:$B$12,$A$2:$A$12=A2), ,2))`

I get a `#value` cell error as an array, the same shape as the result of the filter

Can anyone help me avoid the intermediate step and figure out how to get this into a single formula? thanks in advance.

[image]

**AMEND**
Thanks to @JvdV for a solution using an alternative aproach - I would be interested to know why I cant get around the error - what is it about the return value of one function that prevents me passing it to the next function? Thanks all

Comment: It looks `RANK.EQ` won't accept an array that doesn't tie back to a cell range in the second argument.  `=RANK.EQ(1, {1,2,3})` also doesn't work.  I have had issues trying to use other functions like `SUMIFS` in a similar manner.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe just use `COUNTIFS()`:

[image]

Formula in `D2`:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A12,A2:A12,B2:B12,">"&B2:B12)+1
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, your answer definitely answers " how to get this into a single formula". I would like to understand why I cant get around the error - what is it about the resturn value of one function that prevents me passing it to the next function

Comment: @JohnnieL, `RANK.EQ()` does appear to need a direct reference to a range of cell, not a calculated field, hence the error (that's my understanding of it at least). For example `=RANK.EQ(5,SEQUENCE(5))` won't budge either.

Comment: yes - I think thats the conclusion - just frustrating not to be able to understand why ... I've trawled the microsoft docs no joy - many thanks for taking the time I do appreciate that